# Get random number in ng-repeat angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to get a random number in my cycle angular. I tried this in my template:

```
   <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Base" >
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
      <img ng-src="/img/img{{getRandomImg()}}.png"> 
    </div>
   </div>
```

And function in my Base controller:

```
$scope.getRandomImg = function(){
    return Math.floor((Math.random()*3)+1);
}
```

When my page loaded i have error:
**$rootScope:infdig Infinite $digest Loop**

I also tried to do this with the directive

```
app.directive('randomImage', [
    function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
                var rand = Math.floor((Math.random()*3)+1);

                $(element).attr('src', '/img/tracks/trackimg'+rand+'.png');
            }
        }

    }
]);
```

And in my template:

```
 <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Base" ng-repeat="item in items">
      <img data-random-image=""> 
 </div>
```

It works almost correctly. BUT when I update `items` in my controller is not re-generated images, but remain the same. Why?

Comment: Why don't you just add `imageUrl` as a new property to your `items` elements? And then generate the random number in the controller when populating this collection - it will be much easier to display then: `<img ng-src="item.imageUrl" />`

Comment: what is "items" where is coming from?

Comment: @OlegYudovich, we can assume that it is a variable stored in the current scope inside the controller.

Comment: @ Darin Dimitrov It would be nice, but I have been working with the stored procedure in the database to which I have no access.

Comment: your html page references a  ```getRandImg``` function which is different to your controllers ``getRandomImg```

Comment: @Paul Fitzgerald is a typo in question. i fixed this

Comment: @iillexial, what Darin is saying is a good way to approach this. Irrespective of where you are getting this data from, you can always add an additional property to your item object (for example imageid) and set it to a random number after you get the items from stored proc, just by doing a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is from angular documentation:

"This error occurs when the application's model becomes unstable and each $digest cycle triggers a state change and subsequent $digest cycle. Angular detects this situation and prevents an infinite loop from causing the browser to become unresponsive.

For example, the situation can occur by setting up a watch on a path and subsequently updating the same path when the value changes."

```
<div ng-repeat="user in getUsers()">{{ user.name }}</div>

...

$scope.getUsers = function() {
  return [ { name: 'Hank' }, { name: 'Francisco' } ];
};
```

The problem is in your "items" array.
Read this: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig

Comment: Yes, I know why the error occurs. But I would like to hear alternative solutions for my problem

Comment: You can use : $scope.quantity = 100; and in your binding: ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo:quantity"

Comment: Do you have images render limit?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is you are repeating `ng-controller` & `ng-app` directive too many times using `ng-repeat`

```
 <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Base">
     <div ng-repeat="item in items">
        <img data-random-image=""> 
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: This is just an example for the question. Not the problem